# Re-using a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I have `UIViewController1` and I have it present `UIViewController2` modally, but I then want `UIViewController2` to present `UIViewController1` modally as well but with slightly different functionality, what is best practice for re-usal? I not only want the `UI Elements` to be similar, but most of the logic should be the same as well. The one key difference is that the second time `UIViewController1` is presented, it will be using a different `Prototype UITableViewCell`.

**Edit**

Is it ok to have a loop in navigation workflow?

[image]

Comment: If there are slight differences in behaviour and layout you could create an initWithCell:(UITableViewCell*) method for UIViewController1. If there are more substantial differences in behaviour you could have a base class and two derived sub classes.

Comment: @MartinH Could you take a look at my edit above please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reuse the class again, Drag n drop a new `ViewController` to your Storyboard and re-assign it the same controller class.

Best practice is not to mix logic with `UI` so you can reuse it, that's all `MVC` is about

Comment: actually quick question with this method though...how would I set some flag that tells my ViewController it should provide logic for view1, and then similarly to provide slightly different logic for view2. Can I have some BOOL property?

Comment: and actually, would I have to completely rebuild the UI (prototype cells, other custom UIViews) for the second ViewController in my storyboard and then re-assign delegates, outlets, etc.? There must be an easier way

Comment: If you have different logic than it defeats the concept of reusability, you dont have to recreate your UI you should be able to just copy paste it

Comment: As for the flag perhaps you can set them before you present the view

Comment: could I set the flag from the AppDelegate if this view is the initial ViewController? Sorry I'm still trying to learn the ropes of iOS Dev

Comment: @Auser if appdelegate is presenting that ViewController then absolutely

Comment: But the ViewController is instantiated automatically by storyboard, not programmatically from my AppDelegate. How would I set a flag this way? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @rmeda Yes that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @rmeda it says I need to log in?

Comment: Yeah its not working there is a link here that says  `Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?` but when I click it fails

Comment: @rmeda I suppose these comments could be deleted after this exchange, at the risk of bugging some moderators. Basically what I'm doing is using storyboard to start my app on ViewController1 (i.e. it's never presented programmatically, so currently there's no way I can see of to set a flag property on ViewController1. I suppose I could just present the ViewController from the appDelegate and set the flag there?

Comment: @Auser Yes you can do that or when you present your code modally then you pass it there. If you need to set flags you will need to somehow do it programatically. As you Create an instance of the controller you would just set that Boolean property. If you have some code maybe you should add it if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

If the difference of UITableViewCell is only layout and presentation layer difference I would just use the same `UIViewController1` and define two separate cell identifier and logic in `cellForRow...`

Comment: If I'm presenting my UIViewControllers using storyboard (like in my edit above) can I have a loop in my navigation workflow?